# useRouter and pull part of address and do filtering accordingly

Tags: reactjs, next.js, filter, onclick, router

There is a filter component on my main page:

`<Filters clickFunction={clickFunction} checkedSpecialty={checkedItems} />`

When clicking each specialty it filters the list of consultants accordingly and also brings that speciality to the URL address via this function:

```
const clickFunction = (value) => {
  const newCheckedItems = checkedItems.includes(value)
      ? checkedItems.filter((item) => item !== value)
      : [...checkedItems, value];
      setCheckedItems(newCheckedItems);
      router.push(`/psychology/psychologychildren/psychologists/?specialty=${newCheckedItems.join(',')}`);
};
```

Also, I want to filter psychologists from psychologychildren page, I've added the filtered specialty to the end of the related url via:

`` <Link href={`/psychology/psychologychildren/psychologists/?specialty=${service.text}`}>{service.text}</Link> ``

Now, I need to pull the speciality from the URL of the main page and set the clickfunction so that set checkedItems according to that speciality. Can you help me with it?